# Hyperledger Fabric registerTxEvent fails with "could not decode the PEM structure"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I have Hyperledger Fabric running using the *byfn.sh* script and I’m trying to use the node SDK to write a transaction.

In my setup I a new User object using my Admin private key and certificate and call **client.setUserContext** with that User.

I call **channel.sendTransactionProposal** successfully and follow up with a successful call to **channel.sendTransaction**.

I’m trying to get to a point where I can call **event_hub.registerTxEvent** to find out when the transaction is written on the peers, but I get an error.  My code looks like this:

```
event_hub = client.getEventHubsForOrg()[0]
event_hub.connect()
event_hub.registerTxEvent(tx_id.getTransactionID(), (tx, code) => {
    // This never executes
}, (err) => {
    // An error occurs
})
```

I get the error:

```
Error: 2 UNKNOWN: event message validation failed: [failed deserializing event creator: [could not decode the PEM structure]]
```

It seems the error comes from the Peer when the event hub tries to send a register message and the peer can’t decode it.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?